# downloading to a file in Java - very slow

Tags: java

Given the following example code:

```
somefile = new URL("http://somefile.rar");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(somefile.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test");
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
```

The file in question is 14MB.  When I download it using the code above, it takes 26-30 seconds every time. I noticed that, when downloading it from java, there are periods where no bytes are being transferred at all.  When I download the same file from, say, a browser, it downloads in 4 seconds or less.  Any idea what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using channels is a nice idea, since you can this way avoid superfluous copying of data in memory. But you are using not a real socket-channel here, but a wrapper channel around the InputStream from your URL, which ruins your experience.

You may be able to implement the HTTP protocol yourself using a SocketChannel, or find some library which allows this. (But then, if the result is sent using chunked-encoding, you'll still have to parse this yourself.)

So, the easier way would be to use simply the usual stream copying way given by the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen this way of downloading. Maybe you should try with a `BufferedInputStream`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yourfile.rar");
File target = new File("package.rar");

try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())) {
    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target))) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bos.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion - why don't try removing the channels and work only with the streams. For example you can use commons-io

```
IOUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(somefile.openStream()), 
       new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
// of course, you'd have to close the streams at the end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to use common-io to download file :

```
FileUtils.copyUrlToFile(URL url, String destination);
```